# Como hago para que la regex busque coincidencia textual y que tome como distinto si luego o antes hay otras cosas

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, condiciones

```py
patron_directo_n = r"(?:estoy bien|estoy|estoy bien!|ya estoy|estaba|ya estaba|ya estaba eso|ya estaba esto|ya estaba esta)"
    n = re.search(patron_directo_n, input_text, re.IGNORECASE)

    if n:
        answer_num = random.randint(1, 4)

        if answer_num == 1:
            text = "Oh ya veo"
        elif answer_num == 2:
            text = "Oh vaya ya veo que estas"
        elif answer_num == 3:
            text = "Oh eso veo"
        elif answer_num == 4:
            text = "Ohh eso parece"

    else:
        pass
```

como hago para que la regex solo agarre cuando es textualmente es eso, y no cuando empieza o termina con otra cosa.

Quiero que se active solo cuando digo
"estoy bien"
o alguna de las frases establecidas (textuales)

pero no si pongo
"realmente estoy bien"
"realmente estoy bien ahora"

Comment: ¿Comparar un string con otro ...?

Comment: quiero que compare y que si es una de esas opciones que entre al if, el tema es que si dentro de la oracion esta alguna de esas opciones la regex manda True , pero la idea es que solo sea True si y solo si el input_text es exacamente igual (osea importa como empieza y como termina)

Comment: quitando el re.search() por re.match() pude hacer que este obligado a empezar como dice el patron, lo que todavia me queda es como hacer para que termine en ese patron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tu expresión regular solo le  hace falta incluir los  caracteres de  inicio `^` y fin `$` para lograr lo que  quieres:

```
patron_directo_n = r"^(?:estoy bien|estoy|estoy bien!|ya estoy|estaba|ya estaba|ya estaba eso|ya estaba esto|ya estaba esta)$"
```

Lo anterior  hace que evalue la el texto de inicio a fin y como no hoy comodines, entonces, evaluará contra el texto completo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: de hecho con el signo `?` estas indicando que debe ir cualquier cosa antes de las palabras.

Comment: Está  unido a los ":" indicando que no capture grupo (como toda la expresión esta entre "()") . Si le quitas los  ":" las expresión seria inválida porque como condicional no tiene nada  delante de éste.

Answer (score 1):

Para lo que pides no necesitas expresiones regulares; basta con comparar cadenas.

Primero definamos dos listas:

```
validas = ["estoy bien", "estoy", "estoy bien!", "ya estoy", "estaba", "ya estaba", "ya estaba eso", "ya estaba esto","ya estaba esta"]
respuestas = ["Oh ya veo", "Oh vaya ya veo que estas", "Oh eso veo","Ohh eso parece"]
```

con los textos aceptables y las respuestas a generar.

Ahora podemos definir una función que recibe el texto y lo busca dentro de la lista `validas`. Si lo encuentra, devuelve una respuesta seleccionada al azar.

Para buscar usamos la función intrínseca `any`. Esta recibe un iterable y retorna `True` si hay al menos un elemento que lo sea. A esta función le pasamos una expresión generadora, que es como una comprensión de lista, pero sin generar la lista completa, si no que elemento a elemento según se necesite.

Si no lo encuentra la palabra, devuelve `None`.

```
def respuesta(patron_directo_n, input_text):
    if any(input_text == patron for patron in patron_directo_n):
        answer_num = random.randint(0, len(respuestas))
        return respuestas[answer_num]
    return None
```

**Demo**

```
tests = [
    "",
    "estoy bien",
    "estoy bien acogotado",
    "Oh ya",
    "Oh ya veo",
    "Banana"
]

for test in tests:
    ans = respuesta(validas, test)
    if ans:
        print(f"'{test}' es valida")
    else:
        print(f"'{test}' no es valida")
```

produce

```
'' no es valida
'estoy bien' es valida
'estoy bien acogotado' no es valida
'Oh ya' no es valida
'Oh ya veo' no es valida
'Banana' no es valida

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: yo queria mantener trabajando con regex pero es una buena solucion en este caso, ya que no estoy segura de que halla una regex que ponga "punto final" al patron y que si sigue pos ya lo detecte como un distinto

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda